# Prisma error: Unsafe member access .create on an `any` value

Tags: typescript, prisma, t3

I've ran this command for the T3 boilerplate: npm create t3-app@latest

I then added only the bcrypt and fakerjs library for my prisma seed:

```
{
  "name": "priority",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "next build",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.5",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.14.0",
    "@t3-oss/env-nextjs": "^0.3.1",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.29.7",
    "@trpc/client": "^10.26.0",
    "@trpc/next": "^10.26.0",
    "@trpc/react-query": "^10.26.0",
    "@trpc/server": "^10.26.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "next": "^13.4.2",
    "next-auth": "^4.22.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "superjson": "1.12.2",
    "zod": "^3.21.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^8.0.2",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/eslint": "^8.37.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.16.0",
    "@types/prettier": "^2.7.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "eslint": "^8.40.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.4.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.8",
    "prisma": "^4.14.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "ct3aMetadata": {
    "initVersion": "7.13.2"
  }
}
```

I created my seed file inside my prisma dir:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

import { faker } from "@faker-js/faker";

import bcrypt, { hash } from "bcrypt";

import { type Deadline, Priority } from "../src/types/types";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const deadlines: Deadline[] = Array.from({ length: 100 }, () => ({
  title: faker.lorem.sentences({ min: 10, max: 20 }),
  description: faker.lorem.sentences({ min: 3, max: 30 }),
  date: faker.date.future({ years: 1 }),
  priority: faker.helpers.enumValue(Priority),
}));

async function main() {
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash("Matt123$", 12);
  const user = await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      name: "Matt",
      email: "matt@gmail.com",
      hashedPassword,
    },
  });
  const data = deadlines.map((deadline) => {
    return { ...deadline, userId: user.id };
  });
  await prisma.deadline.createMany({
    data,
  });
}

main()
  .then(async () => {
    console.log("seeded!");
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

And defined my schema:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
    provider = "mongodb"
    // NOTE: When using mysql or sqlserver, uncomment the @db.Text annotations in model Account below
    // Further reading:
    // https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/prisma#create-the-prisma-schema
    // https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#string
    url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

enum Priority {
    HIGH
    MEDIUM
    LOW
}

model Deadline {
    id          String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    title       String
    description String?
    date        DateTime
    priority    Priority
    userId      String   @db.ObjectId
    user        User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

// Necessary for Next auth
model Account {
    id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId

    userId String @db.ObjectId

    type              String
    provider          String
    providerAccountId String
    refresh_token     String? // @db.Text
    access_token      String? // @db.Text
    expires_at        Int?
    token_type        String?
    scope             String?
    id_token          String? // @db.Text
    session_state     String?
    user              User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

    @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
    id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId

    sessionToken String   @unique
    userId       String   @db.ObjectId
    expires      DateTime
    user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
    id             String     @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    hashedPassword String?
    name           String?
    email          String?    @unique
    emailVerified  DateTime?
    image          String?
    accounts       Account[]
    sessions       Session[]
    deadlines      Deadline[]
}

model VerificationToken {
    id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId

    identifier String
    token      String   @unique
    expires    DateTime

    @@unique([identifier, token])
}
```

These are the only steps I've taken and yet I'm still getting the following error on my createMany method:

```
Unsafe member access .createMany on an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
Unsafe call of an `any` typed value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
(method) Prisma.DeadlineDelegate<Prisma.RejectOnNotFound | Prisma.RejectPerOperation | undefined>.createMany<{
    data: {
        userId: string;
        title: string;
        description?: string | undefined;
        priority: Priority;
        date: Date;
    }[];
}>(args?: {
    data: {
        userId: string;
        title: string;
        description?: string | undefined;
        priority: Priority;
        date: Date;
    }[];
} | undefined): Prisma.PrismaPromise<...>
Create many Deadlines.

@param args — Arguments to create many Deadlines.

@example

// Create many Deadlines
const deadline = await prisma.deadline.createMany({
  data: {
    // ... provide data here
  }
})
```

I have no clue what's going on, I've deleted and reinstalled the app like 3 times and I've been at this for atleast an hour.

Here's my tsconfig, figured it might help somehow even though I didnt touch it:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    ".eslintrc.cjs",
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.cjs",
    "**/*.mjs"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `prisma generate` command.

Prisma need to generate code from schema file in order to get type in typescript.

more info [Prisma generate client concept](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/generating-prisma-client)

Not sure this will help or not. But maybe it's help some people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you have run `prisma generate` to create your type schemas and are still getting this typescript warning; restarting your IDE will most likely fix the issue.

I run into issues like this often after adding new entries to the `schema.prisma` file.